# How to delete a gridview row using Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

How do I use this jQuery function to remove a row.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("tr").filter(function() {
        return $('td', this).length && !$('table', this).length
    }).click(function() {
        $(this).remove();
    });

    //enter code here 
});
```

It will delete a row when I mouse hover and click on a row, but in my gridview render as a table and it contains a `tr` that has a one hidden control and it has a `id`.

```html
<tr style="color: #244D8D; background-color: #FFFBD6;" ondblclick="selectRow_gvResults_gov(0,6532,0)">
    <td>
        <input type="hidden" value="6532" id="MainContent_gvResults_gov_hdDocID_0" name="ctl00$MainContent$gvResults_gov$ctl02$hdTocID">
    </td>
    <td>
        1010041215
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here I have another control delete button, in delete button I will get a id to delete, here I want to  pass that id as a parameter to script function ,
and I want to search hidden field contains those value and delete that row.

```vb
Private Sub btnDelete_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
    'some operations
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, GetType(String), "Deletearow", "DeleteGrid_Row(" & Me.hfSelected_GvResultsRowTocID.Value & ");", True)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what exactly you wish to delete and on which event. The following code will deleted the selected td when clicked or when mouse hovers over it.

```
$("the-td-to-be-deleted").bind("click hover", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```js
$('#1010041215').remove();
```